# How can i send multiple nested object to the html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send multi nested object to the html code but nothing work with me?

this is the server side script

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var countries= [{
        userName:"TEST",
        email:"TEST@gmail.com",
        cities:[
            {name: "Riyadh"},
            {name: "Jeddah"},
            {name: "Qasim"}
        ]
    }];
    data.countries.push(countries);
}
```

and from the HTML this is my code

username
        email
        city

```
</tr>
   <tr      ng-repeat="country in data.countries">

    <td >{{::country.userName}}</td>
            <td >{{::country.email}}</td>
     
     <td>
       <span   ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
             {{::city.name}}
       </span>

     </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you define an *array with an object* then push that array onto your array, simply remove the outer array.

from: `var countries = [{}]`

to: `var countries = {}`

Or just push the object to the array, no need to assign it to a var first:

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    data.countries.push({
        userName:"TEST",
        email:"TEST@gmail.com",
        cities:[
            {name: "Riyadh"},
            {name: "Jeddah"},
            {name: "Qasim"}
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: np, glad to help

Comment: its works fine now but let me ask you something please

Comment: I think that warrants another question

Comment: its a simple question, I need to set the value into the city key through the server(GlideRecord)

Comment: while(getusers.next()) {
  var countries= {
        userName:"TEST",
        email:"TEST@gmail.com",
        cities:[
            {name: "Riyadh"},
            {name: "Jeddah"},
            {name: "Qasim"}
        ]
    };
    data.countries.push(countries);

}

Comment: I don't use GlideRecord nor angular since v1, that's why I said :) I'm presuming .next() is a generator, so if it returns false when done use `while(let user = getusers.next())` then you can do something with user.value.

Comment: or change to a for loop `for (let user of getusers()) {`